# TableServiceContext won't serialize ValueObjects

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have the following data structure:

```
[DataServiceEntity]
public class User
{
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public AddressValueObject Address { get; set; }
}

[DataServiceEntity]
public class AddressValueObject
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm creating a new instance of the User class and try to persist it into the Windows Azure Table Storage Emulator using following method:

```
void CreateAndSaveNewUser()
{
    var userInstance = new User
    {
        RowKey = "SomeRowKey",
        PartitionKey = "SomePartitionKey",
        Address = new AddressValueObject
        {
            City = "SomeCity",
            Street = "SomeStreet"
        }
     };

     var tableServiceContext = CloudStorageAccount
                               .DevelopmentStorageAccount
                               .CreateCloudTableClient()
                               .GetDataServiceContext();

     tableServiceContext.AddObject("UserTable", userInstance);

     tableServiceContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is now that the AddressValueObject is not serialized correctly.
In the storage there is only one column called AddressValueObject which is emtpy.

**No columns for AddressValueObject_City and AddressValueObject_Street are created.**

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some attribute?

Does Azure Table Storage even support referenced ValueObjects??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you cannot do that. The Table Storage is a plain simple table and doesn't supports complex types. Consequently relations or constraints are not supported. 
As a workaround you may think to store the partition key and the row key of the related object stored in another table.
If you want to use relations, then the best choice is SQL Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Fabio Cozzolino is correct. The Microsoft Azure table storage client does not support serialization. However you can manually serialize your object and store it as an XML string or byte[].

I have written an client that supports serialization out of the box. I also includes many other features like arrays, enums and data larger than 64K. You can check it out at www.lucifure.com or download Lucifure Stash via NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the ObjectFlattenerRecomposer API in Nuget that allows writing and reading complex objects to/from Azure Table Storage.

Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer/

Blog: https://doguarslan.wordpress.com/2016/02/03/writing-complex-objects-to-azure-table-storage/

The API provides functionality to flatten complex objects into EntityProperty dictionary and functionality to recompose original complex object from the flattened property dictionary. One usage is that the API allows writing any complex object with nested properties into Azure Table Storage in flattened form which is not normally possible by using the Azure Storage Client SDK.

The API also allows you to save Enum, TimeSpan, DateTimeOffset, Nullable property types to Azure Table Storage which is also not possible via Azure Storage Client SDK.

Usage:

using ObjectFlattenerRecomposer;

//Flatten object and convert it to EntityProperty Dictionary

Dictionary flattenedProperties = EntityPropertyConverter.Flatten(complexObject);

// Create a DynamicTableEntity and set its PK and RK

DynamicTableEntity dynamicTableEntity = new DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey);

dynamicTableEntity.Properties = flattenedProperties;

// Write the DynamicTableEntity to Azure Table Storage using client SDK

//Read the entity back from AzureTableStorage as DynamicTableEntity using the same PK and RK

DynamicTableEntity entity = [Read from Azure using the PK and RK];

//Convert the DynamicTableEntity back to original complex object.

Imagine original complexObject was of type Order.

Order order = EntityPropertyConverter.ConvertBack(entity.Properties);